Trying to implant MD simulation for alloying two atoms to Python
I am trying to design the python code for alloying two particles using Molecular Dynamics simulation. Usually, a lot of research group use LAAMPS or other else. But, I am newbies for the those program use, so now I try to add most of the physics to the code below for MD simulation of alloying atoms at certain conditions.
The code below looked working well, but the atoms do not interact each other. In other words, the final result does not show the cluster form as the temperature increases. It just looked like randomly distributed atoms even if the system change the temperature. When I checked the reference paper's results from other simulators, such as LAAMPS, Atomsk, the two atoms should become a cluster form at around 7-800 C. So, if anyone can help me to revise the code below that includes any physics do I miss.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define physical constants
Avogadro = 6.02214086e23
Boltzmann = 1.38064852e-23  # Boltzmann constant in J/K

# Define physical parameters for Pd and Au atoms
# Mass, initial positions, etc.
pd_mass = 106.42 / Avogadro  # Pd atomic mass in kg
au_mass = 196.97 / Avogadro  # Au atomic mass in kg

# Total number of atoms for each metal
n_pd = 50
n_au = 50
natoms = n_pd + n_au

# Define simulation box size
box_size = (10e-7, 10e-7, 10e-7)  # 1 micrometers x 1 micrometers x 1 micrometers

# Function to generate initial positions of atoms within the simulation box
def generate_initial_positions(natoms, box_size):
    initial_positions = np.random.rand(natoms, 3) * box_size
    return initial_positions

# Function to generate initial velocities of particles based on Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution
def generate_initial_velocities(natoms, temperature):
    mean_speed = np.sqrt(3 * Boltzmann * temperature / np.mean([pd_mass, au_mass]))  # Mean speed from kinetic theory
    velocities = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=mean_speed, size=(natoms, 3))
    return velocities

# Initialize particle positions and velocities within the simulation box
temperature_start = 100  # Initial temperature in °C
initial_positions = generate_initial_positions(natoms, box_size)
initial_velocities = generate_initial_velocities(natoms, temperature_start)

# Define simulation parameters
temperature_end = 800  # Final temperature in °C
heating_rate = 100 / 60  # Heating rate in °C per minute
dt = 0.1  # Timestep for simulation in minutes

# Function to compute Lennard-Jones potential between two atoms with modified parameters for clustering
def lj_potential(r, temperature):
    # Adjust LJ parameters based on temperature
    sigma = 2.88e-10  # Au-Au LJ parameter (m)
    epsilon = 1.0e-20  # Interaction strength parameter (J)
    # Increase epsilon (strength of interaction) as temperature increases
    epsilon *= (temperature / 100)
    
    # Original LJ potential
    return 4 * epsilon * ((sigma / r) ** 12 - (sigma / r) ** 6)

# Function to compute forces between atoms using LJ potential
def computeForces(positions, temperature):
    forces = np.zeros_like(positions)
    for i in range(natoms):
        for j in range(i + 1, natoms):
            r = np.linalg.norm(positions[i] - positions[j])
            if r != 0:
                force = lj_potential(r, temperature) * (positions[i] - positions[j]) / r
                forces[i] += force
                forces[j] -= force
    return forces
    
# Function to integrate particle motions using Verlet integration
def integrate(positions, velocities, forces, masses, dt, temperature):
    # Repeat masses for each atom
    masses = np.repeat(masses, positions.shape[0] // len(masses))

    # Perform element-wise multiplication with properly shaped masses
    positions += velocities * dt + 0.5 * forces / masses[:, np.newaxis] * dt**2
    new_forces = computeForces(positions, temperature)
    velocities += 0.5 * (forces + new_forces) / masses[:, np.newaxis] * dt
    forces = new_forces
    return positions, velocities, forces

# Update simulation box size based on thermal expansion
def update_box_size(box_size, temperature):
    # Apply thermal expansion to the box size based on the coefficient of thermal expansion for the alloy
    # You can use a linear expansion model or a more complex model depending on the material properties
    thermal_expansion_coefficient = 1e-5  # Example coefficient for illustration
    new_box_size = tuple([size * (1 + thermal_expansion_coefficient * (temperature - temperature_start)) for size in box_size])
    return new_box_size

# Function to find clusters of atoms based on a cutoff distance
def find_clusters(positions, cutoff_distance):
    n_atoms = positions.shape[0]
    clusters = []
    visited = np.zeros(n_atoms, dtype=bool)

    def dfs(node, cluster):
        visited[node] = True
        cluster.append(node)
        for i in range(n_atoms):
            if not visited[i] and np.linalg.norm(positions[node] - positions[i]) <= cutoff_distance:
                dfs(i, cluster)

    for i in range(n_atoms):
        if not visited[i]:
            cluster = []
            dfs(i, cluster)
            clusters.append(cluster)

    return clusters

current_temperature = temperature_start
snapshot_increment = 100  # Temperature increment for snapshots
snapshot_counter = 0

while current_temperature <= temperature_end:
    # Compute forces between particles
    forces = computeForces(initial_positions, current_temperature)

    # Integrate particle motions
    initial_positions, _, forces = integrate(initial_positions, initial_velocities, forces, np.array([pd_mass, au_mass]), dt, current_temperature)

    # Update box size based on thermal expansion
    box_size = update_box_size(box_size, current_temperature)

    # Apply periodic boundary conditions
    initial_positions = initial_positions % box_size

    # Find clusters of atoms based on a cutoff distance
    cutoff_distance = 2.5e-10  # Cutoff distance for clustering (adjust as needed)
    clusters = find_clusters(initial_positions, cutoff_distance)

    # Plot clusters for every 50°C increment
    if snapshot_counter % snapshot_increment == 0:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        plotted_labels = set()  # To keep track of plotted labels
        for i, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
            for atom in cluster:
                if atom < n_pd:
                    label = 'Pd'
                    color = 'r'
                else:
                    label = 'Au'
                    color = 'b'
                if label not in plotted_labels:
                    ax.scatter(initial_positions[atom, 0], initial_positions[atom, 1], initial_positions[atom, 2], c=color, label=label, s=5)
                    plotted_labels.add(label)
                else:
                    ax.scatter(initial_positions[atom, 0], initial_positions[atom, 1], initial_positions[atom, 2], c=color, s=5)
        ax.set_xlim(0, box_size[0])
        ax.set_ylim(0, box_size[1])
        ax.set_zlim(0, box_size[2])
        ax.set_xlabel('X Position')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y Position')
        ax.set_zlabel('Z Position')
        ax.set_title(f'Clusters at {current_temperature}°C')
        ax.legend()
        plt.show()

    # Update temperature for next timestep
    current_temperature += heating_rate * dt
    snapshot_counter += 1


this appears to be more of a Physics question than a coding question.  It would be helpful to identify which function are you having problems with or which function is not producing the expected result.  minimal reproducible example
